# Declare a list of user defined class in python

Tags: python, list, class, cluster-computing

I have:

```
class Cluster:
    # some attributes

c = Cluster()
```

where `c` should be a list of type `Cluster()`

Can I define something like `c= Cluster[]` ?

I am a beginner at python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify: there is **no such thing** as a "list of type `Cluster`". There is a list of type `list`, it can contain anything.

So you need to create a bunch of `Cluster`s and add them to a regular list:

e.g. with a list comprehension:

```
N = 10 # length
clusters = [Cluster() for _ in range(N)]
```

or with a regular loop:

```
clusters = []
for _ in range(N): clusters.append(Cluster())
```

In any case you can modify your list later on, because it's just a regular list.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = [Cluster(arguments), Cluster(arguments2), ... ]
```

Is the same as:

```
a = [1 , 2, "a" , 4, Cluster(arguments3)]
```

Comment: I dont know the size of my cluster at the beginning, can it be initialized such that it may be appended later?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you don't have to (and you can't) tell what will your list contain. So just make empty list

```
c=[]
```

and than call

```
c.append(thing)
```

for things you want: thing can be of type int, Cluster, float etc. At the end, you can have

```
c=[Cluster(...),1,"2",["a",1.2],(2,3),{1,2,3}]
```

(where {1,2,3} is a set and (2,3) is a tuple).

Answer (score 0):

Just write `c = []`, and then add `Cluster` objects to your `list` c like this:

```
c = []
obj = Cluster()
c += [obj]
```